# Updating nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain, domain-name, domain-registration

I'm trying to update nameservers to point to myhost.net but for some reason there's a domain pointer with my website name at anotherhost.com

Domain Servers
ns2.myhost.net
ns1.myhost.net

Points to:
mywebsitename.anotherhost.com

It seems it's not propagating the last 24 hours.  Is this correct?  Should there be a domain pointer pointing to another host?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry i'm having a bit of trouble figuring out what you are asking. Are you setting up DNS on your own servers, and you want them to resolve for your domain, but currently a hosting provider is setup as the name servers?

Comment: No. From one hosting to another.  But the old hosting is still showing up as a domain pointer. Sorry if I'm not making much sense, I'm new at this.  Will it affect the update if there is a domain pointer that is pointing to the old host?

Comment: @dm66 no worries, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `whois myhost.net` - this will tell you the domain registrar that's managing your domain name records.
Log into that domain registrar's system and change the domain name servers for your domain through their interface.

If you are trying to use DNS servers whose names are inside the domain they're serving (e.g, if the DNS servers for myhost.net are named something like ns1.myhost.net instead of ns1.somethingelse.net) then you will need to include "glue records" that provide the actual IP addresses of your name servers - otherwise you'd have an infinite loop of lookups (e.g., to resolve www.myhost.net, you'd need to talk to the server at ns1.myhost.net, and to get *that* address, you've gotta talk to ns1.myhost.net, ad nauseum)

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is go into your registrar's control panel and change the DNS servers that are assigned to your domain. This will vary by registrar.

Your new hosting provider should have given you a set of DNS servers to specify at your registrar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've done that already.  I'll just go ahead and mention the host - - I'm trying to point the dns to h2hosting and I have gone in the Cpanel and did it by the ns1...  However, blue domain is the old hosting and I noticed that there is a domain pointer to mysite.bluedomain.com  Should there be a pointer pointing to bluedomain or shouldn't it be pointing to the new host (h2hosting)?  Will it affect the update?

Comment: @dm66 Where did you register the domain at? bluedomain.com?

Comment: Yes - at Blue Domain